# How to switch off HP printer catridge protection / check the ink level / check printer messages?

Tags: drivers, printing, hp

I bought refurbished [HP Deskjet 1110](https://support.hp.com/gb-en/product/hp-deskjet-1110-printer-series/7174529/manuals) printer. The seller included non-original 302xl catridges.

On my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, I installed HPLIP package from [HP](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/gethplip).

When I inserted catridges, Power button light started to blinking fast.
According to user guide, it means that:

```
The printer is in an error state that you can resolve by following the on-screen messages from the 
computer. If you do not see any on-screen messages, try printing a document to generate an onscreen message
```

Unfortunately, I can't see such message and I am unable to print anything. In HP utility in status there are no messages (status is "unknown"). However, I've noticed that mentioned app reports that black ink is empty:

[image: no black ink]
[image: HP utility for printing]

1. Is it possible that this is caused by the original catridges protection? How can I switch it off? I can't find any information how to do that, all instructions are for Windows only. I can't see appropriate option in HP Device Manager.
2. Is it possible to check printer messages directly? I have that impression that on M$ Windows machine, after switching on printer, I would immediately see detailed error message, while on Linux I can only guess what is wrong (or try to search tons of log messages in console).

---

**EDIT**

I installed Windows 7 in Virtual machine (Oracle VirtualBox with extensions that allow to use USB devices). Then I downloaded and executed 'DJ1110_Full_WebPack_40.11.1124.exe' to install official driver for HP DeskJet 1110.

I discovered that in Windows, following setting is available that I can't find in HPLIP:

[image: Catridge Protection in Windows HP driver]

This allowed me to unlock black catridge, but I wasn't able to use color catridge - Windows driver reported that it's broken.

---

**Solution**

I bought new, original HP catdriges and now even HPLIP reports that everything is okay and show me the ink level. I'm able to print.

However, I wonder if it's really possible to switch off catdrige protection on Windows only. Should I ask for adding mentioned setting to HPLIP on their support page?

Comment: I'd suggest heading to the office supply store and getting an original HP cartridge - in my experience, the HP printers are very sensitive to refilled or aftermarket cartridges.

Comment: Just to be clear, the Hplip app is not reporting the cartridge is empty. It is reporting that the cartridge status is unknown.

Comment: @CharlesGreen You were right, I edited my question. However, it seems that Windows driver has some settings that HPLIP hasn't.

Comment: Yup Windows definitely has something extra. I'm able to print from windows using a generic cartridge but Linux reports it having low ink.

Answer (score 1):

I have a HP ENVY 5530 printer but the solution I found may work. Actually you can access the configuration of the printer through "FutureSmart 3 (or 4)". For this,

- find the IP of your printer in the network menu (on the printer itself). On a local network, it is usually 192.168.xx.yy.
- go to this address in a browser (on your computer). You should access a configuration menu
- The go to `parameters > preferences > HP cartridge protection` and choose `disable`

The menu may change from one printer to another. More info can be found [on the HP website](https://support.hp.com/ca-en/document/c05416999).

Comment: Looks promising. Unfortunately, I can't verify your suggestion, because I changed my printer.